# CABasicAnimation Does Not End Smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation

I've the following extension for UIView to perform a buzz animation.

The animation is working fine although the ending is not smooth. For the final animation count, UIView goes `center.x - 40` and returns to `center.x` harshly.

I couldn't get it to make an ending in a smooth manner. How can I achieve this?

```
extension UIView {
    func buzz() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        animation.duration = 0.4
        animation.repeatCount = 2
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 40.0, y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 40.0, y: self.center.y))
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

[image: Animation Preview]

Answer (score 1):

before you do the animation, you need to set the layer's position to where it will be once the animation completes.  That's because the animation runs separately on a different layer which goes away once it completes.

Comment: Got the idea but could you please expend on that by providing a sample code.

Comment: add this line after the opening brace or in the blank line after let animation...:         layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 40.0, y: self.center.y)

Comment: That line of code makes it move only in one direction(the buzz effect is gone) and once it finishes, the view is out of bounds by 40.

Comment: based on the picture of the animation you just added it looks to me like you have more than one animation going on. I think this one is fixed but you might have another one (maybe right before this is called...) Is that possible?

Comment: What's that flashing stuff in the top right corner?

Comment: That's just my screen recorder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136256/discussion-between-mozahler-and-can-surmeli).